# MERGE statement took too long to execute (for just 1 record only). (MS-SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

The issue I"m having is this SQL Merge command took too long to execute?   It still take more than 30 seconds.   We're using MS-SQL 2012 Server.

So, can anyone tell me what I did wrong with the MERGE statement and why?

Thanks...

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spDealerAccount_VehicleSalesRecordReload]    Script Date: 07/02/2014 11:02:21 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- ============================================================================
-- Author:      ...
-- Create date: 07/01/2014
-- Description: 
--      Either creates new or updates existing vehicle inventory record.
--      Record is updated only if ***either*** of following are met:
--          - source AccountID exists
--          - source VIN exists
--          - both source AccountID & VIN exists having no duplicate unique vehicle
-- References:
--      http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx
--      http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert
--      http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx (for explanation of HOLDLOCK)
-- ============================================================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDealerAccount_VehicleSalesRecordReload]
    @parmAccountId              [bigint], 
    @parmBitwiseAcceptedTotal   [bigint],
    @parmYear                   [nvarchar](50),
    @parmMake                   [nvarchar](50),
    @parmModel                  [nvarchar](50),
    @parmTrim                   [nvarchar](80),
    @parmVin                    [nvarchar](17),
    @parmSquishVin              [nvarchar](12),
    @parmVinValidationSkipped   [bit],
    @parmMileage                [int],
    @parmPurchaseDate           [date],
    @parmSaleDate               [date],
    @parmNumOfDays              [int],
    @parmSaleType               [nvarchar](1),
    @parmPurchaseAmount         [money],
    @parmRepairCostAmount       [money],
    @parmSaleAmount             [money],
    @parmTotalTradeAmount       [money],
    @parmGrossProfitAmount      [money],
    @parmZipcode                [nvarchar](50),
    @parmCity                   [nvarchar](50),
    @parmState                  [nvarchar](50),
    @parmRegion                 [nvarchar](50),
    @parmStockNumber            [nvarchar](50),
    @parmLocation               [nvarchar](150),
    @parmDataSourceFrom         [nvarchar](500),
    @parmImportedVersion        [int],
    @parmCondition              [nvarchar](50),
    @parmAccessories            [nvarchar](MAX),
    @parmEngineDetail           [nvarchar](50),
    @parmExteriorColor          [nvarchar](50) 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE 
        INTO [dbo].[tblDealerSalesVehicles] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS t
        USING [dbo].[tblDealerSalesVehicles] AS s
        ON (t.[AccountId] = s.[AccountId] AND t.[Vin] = s.[Vin])
    --  
    -- if matched, update existing record if right conditions are met (see Description in header)   
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET 
            --RawID...
            --AccountID...
            t.[BitwiseAcceptedTotal] = @parmBitwiseAcceptedTotal, 
            t.[Year] = @parmYear,
            t.[Make] = @parmMake,
            t.[Model] = @parmModel,
            t.[Trim] = @parmTrim,
            --VIN...
            --SquishVin...
            --[VinValidationSkipped...
            t.[Mileage] = @parmMileage,
            t.[StockDate] = @parmPurchaseDate,
            t.[SoldDate] = @parmSaleDate,
            t.[NumOfDays] = @parmNumOfDays,
            t.[SaleType] = @parmSaleType,
            t.[PurchPrice] = @parmPurchaseAmount,
            t.[RepairCost] = @parmRepairCostAmount,
            t.[SalePrice] = @parmSaleAmount,
            t.[TotalTrade] = @parmTotalTradeAmount,
            t.[GrossProfit] = @parmGrossProfitAmount,
            t.[Zipcode] = @parmZipcode,
            t.[City] = @parmCity,
            t.[State] = @parmState,
            t.[Region] = @parmRegion,
            t.[StockNo] = @parmStockNumber,
            t.[Location] = @parmLocation,
            t.[DataSourceFrom] = @parmDataSourceFrom,
            t.[ImportedVersion] = @parmImportedVersion,
            t.[ModifiedDate] = GETDATE(),
            --ImportedDate...
            t.[TimeStamp] = GETDATE()
    --             
    -- if not matched, add new record and set return values
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
         --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609208/need-help-with-the-merge-statement...
        --(Cannot use "s." or "t." for source or target table-name-abbreviation cuz "Columns name in the insert list can only refer to the target table, so the parser doesn't expect to see a table alias there, wouldn't know how to resolve it. It sees "column1", it knows it belongs to the target table. It sees "table1.column1", it doesn't know what "table1" means. "table1" is out of scope, so to speak")...
        INSERT (
            --RawID...
            [AccountID], [BitwiseAcceptedTotal],
            [Year], [Make], [Model], [Trim], [VIN], [SquishVin], [VinValidationSkipped],
            [Mileage], [StockDate], [SoldDate], [NumOfDays], [SaleType],
            [PurchPrice], [RepairCost], [SalePrice], 
            [TotalTrade], [GrossProfit], 
            [Zipcode], [City], [State], [Region],
            [StockNo], [Location], 
            [DataSourceFrom], [ImportedVersion], [ModifiedDate], [ImportedDate], [TimeStamp]
        ) 
        VALUES (
            @parmAccountId, @parmBitwiseAcceptedTotal,
            @parmYear, @parmMake, @parmModel, @parmTrim, @parmVin, @parmSquishVin, @parmVinValidationSkipped,
            @parmMileage, @parmPurchaseDate, @parmSaleDate, @parmNumOfDays, @parmSaleType,
            @parmPurchaseAmount, @parmRepairCostAmount, @parmSaleAmount,  
            @parmTotalTradeAmount, @parmGrossProfitAmount,  
            @parmZipcode, @parmCity, @parmState, @parmRegion, 
            @parmStockNumber, @parmLocation, 
            @parmDataSourceFrom, @parmImportedVersion, NULL, GETDATE(), GETDATE()
        )
    ; -- required semicolon separator for MERGE

    RETURN @@ERROR; 
END
```

Comment: How large are your tables?  Do you have an index on AccountId and Vin?  Is the behavior consistent across multiple runs?

Comment: Why the `HOLDLOCK`? Remove it and try again. To see what actually happens, execute the query with the '[Display Actual Execution Plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189562.aspx)' option enabled.

Comment: [Vulcronos] - Yes, DB Index already there for AccountID and VIN.  The table is pretty big (few billions rows).   But it works pretty fast if I use standalone INSERT only or standalone UPDATE only.

Comment: [Panagiotis K.] - I'm afraid it wouldn't work cuz the database server is on different network, firewall blocking ports and database server.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: please read stored procedure's comments from the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think your MERGE statement is doing what you expect. You have the same source and target, with no link to the parameters, so this bit:

```
MERGE
    INTO [dbo].[tblDealerSalesVehicles] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS t
    USING [dbo].[tblDealerSalesVehicles] AS s
    ON (t.[AccountId] = s.[AccountId] AND t.[Vin] = s.[Vin])
```

will match every existing record and update it with your parameters. You probably want to use something like:

```
MERGE 
    INTO [dbo].[tblDealerSalesVehicles] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS t
    USING (VALUES (@parmAccountId, @ParamVin)) AS s (AccountID, Vin)
    ON (t.[AccountId] = s.[AccountId] AND t.[Vin] = s.[Vin])
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
  ....etc
```

Comment: Nice.  It works great!!!  Reading this SQL Syntax is mind-boggling though ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx )