# High CPU usage when SQL MERGE of 2,000 vehicles per second

Tags: sql-server, merge, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Two questions here.

1) Does anyone know why am I getting high CPU usage when doing merge of 2,000 vehicles per second?

2) Curious, is there a way to do merge of 10,000 vehicles per second without high CPU usage as well?

```
//Table & Index syntax...
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dealer_SalesVehicles](
    [RawID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [StockNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Vin] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Year] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Make] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Style] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Dealer_SalesVehicles_AccountId_StockNumber_Vin] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AccountID] ASC,
    [StockNumber] ASC,
    [Vin] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

//Sql Query...
var sqlAsk = "";
var rowAffected = 0;
var errorSqlParameters = new List<Tuple<string, string>>(); ;

using (var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(this._databaseConnectionString))
{
   using (var dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
   {
       sqlAsk = "";
       sqlAsk += " MERGE ";
       sqlAsk += "     TOP (1)[dbo].[Dealer_SalesVehicles] WITH(HOLDLOCK) AS t ";
       sqlAsk += "     USING ";
       sqlAsk += "         (SELECT ";
       sqlAsk += "             @parmAccountId, @parmStockNumber, @parmVin ";
       sqlAsk += "         ) ";
       sqlAsk += "         AS s ";
       sqlAsk += "         ( ";
       sqlAsk += "             [AccountID], [StockNumber], [VIN] ";
       sqlAsk += "         ) ";
       sqlAsk += "     ON(t.[AccountId] = s.[AccountId] AND t.[StockNumber] = s.[StockNumber] AND t.[Vin] = s.[Vin]) ";
       //#-- if matched, update existing record if right conditions are met(see Description in header)...
       sqlAsk += " WHEN MATCHED AND(t.[AccountId] = s.[AccountId]) AND t.[StockNumber] = s.[StockNumber] AND(t.[Vin] = s.[Vin]) THEN ";
       sqlAsk += "     UPDATE SET ";
       //AccountID...
       //StockNumber...
       //VIN...
       sqlAsk += "         t.[Year] = @parmYear, ";
       sqlAsk += "         t.[Make] = @parmMake, ";
       sqlAsk += "         t.[Model] = @parmModel, ";
       sqlAsk += "         t.[Style] = @parmStyle ";
       //#-- if not matched, add new record and set return values...
       sqlAsk += " WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN ";
       //#--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609208/need-help-with-the-merge-statement...
       //#--(Cannot use "s." or "t." here, for source or target table - name - abbreviation cuz "Columns name in the insert list can only refer to the target table, so the parser doesn't expect to see a table alias there, wouldn't know how to resolve it. It sees "column1", it knows it belongs to the target table. It sees "table1.column1", it doesn't know what "table1" means. "table1" is out of scope, so to speak")...
       sqlAsk += "     INSERT( ";
       //RawID...
       sqlAsk += "         [AccountID], [StockNumber], [VIN], ";
       sqlAsk += "         [Year], [Make], [Model], [Style] ";
       sqlAsk += "     ) ";
       sqlAsk += "     VALUES( ";
       sqlAsk += "         @parmAccountId, @parmStockNumber, @parmVin, ";
       sqlAsk += "         @parmYear, @parmMake, @parmModel, @parmStyle ";
       sqlAsk += "     ) ";
       sqlAsk += " ; ";  //#--required semicolon separator for MERGE....

       dbCommand.CommandTimeout = 60;
       dbCommand.CommandText = sqlAsk;
       dbCommand.Parameters.Clear();
       dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parmAccountId", SqlDbType.BigInt)).Value = parmSqlSalesVehicleRequest.DealerBranchAccountId;
       dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parmStockNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = parmSqlSalesVehicleRequest.StockNumber;
       dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parmVin", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = parmSqlSalesVehicleRequest.Vin;
       dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parmYear", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = parmSqlSalesVehicleRequest.Year;
       dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parmMake", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = parmSqlSalesVehicleRequest.Make;
       dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parmModel", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = parmSqlSalesVehicleRequest.Model;
       dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parmStyle", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = parmSqlSalesVehicleRequest.Style;

       foreach (SqlParameter sqlParameter in dbCommand.Parameters)
       {
           errorSqlParameters.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(sqlParameter.ParameterName, sqlParameter.Value.ToString()));
       }

       if (dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) { dbConnection.Close(); }

       await dbConnection.OpenAsync();

       rowAffected = await dbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
   }
}
```

Comment: Please check about execution plan reusing...

Comment: Upload all your rows to db, then do your merge for all rows at once.

Comment: Are you calling this script 2000 times ? You should create a Type Userdefined table. Populate this type and pass it to a stored procedure. That way you only need 1 merge

Comment: Actually, we're calling over 1 million records that are coming in from external source (not from database itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a single stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Add
(
    @parmAccountId ...,
    @parmStockNumber
)
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE TOP(1) dbo.Dealer_SalesVehicles WITH (HOLDLOCK) t
    USING (
        SELECT [AccountID] = @parmAccountId,
               [StockNumber] = @parmStockNumber,
               [VIN] = @parmVin
    ) s ON t.[AccountId] = s.[AccountId]
        AND t.[StockNumber] = s.[StockNumber]
        AND t.[Vin] = s.[Vin]
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN UPDATE
            SET
                t.[year] = @parmYear,
                t.[Make] = @parmMake,
                t.[model] = @parmModel,
                t.[style] = @parmStyle
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
        THEN INSERT ([AccountID], [StockNumber], [VIN], [year], [Make], [model], [style])
        VALUES (@parmAccountId, @parmStockNumber, @parmVin, @parmYear, @parmMake, @parmModel, @parmStyle);

END
GO
```

And exec this SP from your code.

Comment: FYI - It wasn't me that got your answer down voted.  Been busy with several projects so I'll get back to this posting when I can.

Comment: That certainly helped.  It was cut down almost in half the time while CPU usage stayed below 10% on Window's task manager.    Any suggestion on speeding it up further?  I processed 5,000 vehicles per 4 seconds, so is it possible to do 10,000 vehicles per second?  Thanks.